# Low level graphics programming and ZBrush

Tags: graphics, 3d, modeling

After a while of 3d modelling and enjoying ZBrush's impeccable performance and numerous features I thought it would be great OpenGL practice for me to create something similar, just a small sculpting tool. Sure enough I got it done, I couldn't match ZBrush's performance of course seeing as how a brigade of well payed professionals outmatch a hobbyist. For the moment I just assumed ZBrush was heavily hardware accelerated, imagine my surprise when I found out it's not and furthermore it uses neither opengl or direct3d.

This made me want to learn graphics on a lower level but I have no clue where to start. How are graphics libraries made and how does one access the framebuffer without the use of opengl. How much of a hassle would it be to display just a single pixel without any preexisting tools and what magic gives ZBrush such performance.

I'd appreciate any info on any question and a recommendation for a book that covers any of these topics. I'm already reading Michael Abrash's Graphics Programming Black Book but it's not really addressing these matters or I just haven't reached that point yet.

Thank you in advance.

(Please don't post answers like "just use opengl" or "learn math", this seems to be the reaction everywhere I post this question but these replies are off topic)

Answer (score 7):

ZBrush is godly in terms of performance but I think it's because it was made by image processing experts with assembly expertise (it's also likely due to the sheer amount of assembly code that they've been almost 20 years late in porting to 64-bit). It actually started out without any kind of 3D sculpting and was just a 2.5D "pixol" painter where you could spray pixels around on a canvas with some depth and lighting to the "pixols". It didn't get sculpting until around ZB 1.5 or so. Even then it impressed people with how fast you could spray these 2.5D "pixols" around on the canvas back when a similarly-sized brush just painting flat pixels with Photoshop or Corel Painter would have brought framerates to a stutter. So they were cutting-edge in performance even before they tackled anything 3D and were doing nothing more than spraying pixels on a canvas; that tends to require some elite micro-optimization wizardry.

One of the things to note about ZB when you're sculpting 20 million polygon models with it is that it doesn't even use GPU rasterization. All the rasterization is done in CPU. As a result it doesn't benefit from a beefy video card with lots of VRAM supporting the latest GLSL/HLSL versions; all it needs is something that can plot colored pixels to a screen. This is probably one of the reasons it uses so little memory compared to, say, MudBox, since it doesn't have to triple the memory usage with, say, VBOs (which tend to double system memory usage while also requiring the data to be stored on the GPU).

As for how you get started with this stuff, IMO a good way to get your feet wet is to write your own raytracer. I don't think ZBrush uses, say, scanline rasterization which tends to rise very proportionally in cost the more polygons you have, since they reduce the number of pixels being rendered at times like when you rotate the model. That suggests that whatever technique they're using for rasterization is more dependent in terms of performance by the number of pixels being rendered rather than the number of primitives (vertices/triangles/lines/voxels) being rendered. Raytracing fits those characteristics. Also IMHO a raytracer is actually easier to write than a scanline rasterizer since you don't have to bother with tricky cases so much and elimination of overdrawing comes free of charge.

Once you got a software where the cost of an operation is more in proportion to the number of pixels being rendered than the amount of geometry, then you can throw a boatload of polygons at it as they did all the way back when they demonstrated 20 million polygon sculpting at Siggraph with silky frame rates almost 17 years ago.

However, it's very difficult to get a raytracer to update interactively in response to mesh data that is being not only sculpted interactively, but sometimes having its topology being changed interactively. So chances are that they are using some data structure other than your standard BVH or KD-Tree as popular in raytracing, and instead a data structure which is well-suited for dynamic meshes that are not only deforming but also having their topology being changed. Maybe they can voxelize and revoxelize (or "pixolize" and "repixolize") meshes on the fly really quickly and cast rays directly into the voxelized representation. That would start to make sense given how their technology originally revolved around these 2.5D "pixels" with depth.

Anyway, I'd suggest raytracing for a start even if it's only just getting your feet wet and getting you nowhere close to ZB's performance just yet (it's still a very good start on how to translate 3D geometry and lighting into an attractive 2D image). You can find minimal examples of raytracers on the web written with just a hundred lines of code. Most of the work typically in building a raytracer is performance and also handling a rich diversity of shaders/materials. You don't necessarily need to bother with the latter and ZBrush doesn't so much either (they use these dirt cheap matcaps for modeling). Then you'll likely have to innovate some kind of data structure that's well-suited for mesh changes to start getting on par with ZB and micro-tune the hell out of it. That software is really on a whole different playing field.

I have likewise been so inspired by ZB but haven't followed in their footsteps directly, instead using the GPU rasterizer and OpenGL. One of the reasons I find it difficult to explore doing all this stuff on the CPU as ZB has is because you lose the benefits of so much industrial research and revolutionary techniques that game engines and NVidia and AMD have come up with into lighting models in realtime and so forth that all benefit from GPU-side processing. There's 99% of the 3D industry and then there's ZBrush in its own little corner doing things that no one else is doing and you need a lot of spare time and maybe a lot of balls to abandon the rest of the industry and try to follow in ZB's footsteps. Still I always wish I could find some spare time to explore a pure CPU rasterizing engine like ZB since they still remain unmatched when your goal is to directly interact with ridiculously high-resolution meshes.

The closest I've gotten to ZB performance was sculpting 2 million polygon meshes at over 30 FPS back in the late 90s on an Athlon T-Bird 1.2ghz with 256MB of RAM, and that was after 6 weeks of intense programming and revisiting the drawing board over and over in a very simplistic demo, and that was a very rare time where my company gave me so much R&D time to explore what ZB was doing. Still, ZB was handling 5 times that geometry at the same frame rates even at that time and on the same hardware and using half the memory. I couldn't even get close, though I did end up with a newfound respect and admiration for the programmers at Pixologic. I also had to insist to my company to do the research. Some of the people there thought ZBrush would never become anything noteworthy and would just remain a cutesy artistic application. I thought the opposite since I saw something revolutionary long before it acquired such an epic following.

A lot of people at the time thought ZB's ability to handle so many polygons was impractical and that you could just paint bump/normal/displacement maps and add whatever details you needed into textures. But that's ignoring the workflow side of things. When you can just work straight with epic amounts of geometry, you get to uniformly apply the same tools and workflow to select vertices, polygons, edges, brush over things, etc. It becomes the most straightforward way to create such a detailed and complex model, after which you can bake out the details into bump/normal/displacement maps for use in other engines that would vomit on 20 million polygons. Nowadays I don't think anyone still questions the practicality of ZB.

> [...] but it's not really addressing these matters or I just haven't
>   reached that point yet.

As a caveat, no one has published anything on how to achieve performance rivaling ZB. Otherwise there would be a number of applications rivaling its performance and features when it comes to sculpting, dynamesh, zspheres, etc and it wouldn't be so amazingly special. You definitely need your share of R&D to come up with anything close to it, but I think raytracing is a good start. After that you'll likely need to come up with some really interesting ideas for algorithms and data structures in addition to a lot of micro-tuning.

What I can say with a fair degree of confidence is that:

1. They have some central data structure to accelerate rasterization that can update extremely quickly in response to changes the user makes to a mesh (including topological ones).
2. The cost of rasterization is more in proportion to the number of pixels rendered rather than the size of the 3D input.
3. There's some micro-optimization wizardry in there, including straight up assembly coding (I'm quite certain ZB uses assembly coding since they were originally requiring programmers to have both assembly and C++ knowledge back when they were hiring in the 2000s; I really wanted to work at Pixologic but lacked the prerequisite assembly skills).
4. Whatever they use is pretty light on memory requirements given that the models are so dynamic. Last time I checked, they use less than 100MB per million polygons even when loading in production models with texture maps. Competing 3D software with the exception of XSI can take over a gigabyte for the same data. XSI uses even less memory than ZB with its gigapoly core but is ill-suited to manipulating such data, slowing down to a crawl (they probably optimized it in a way that's only well-suited for static data like offloading data to disk or even using some expensive forms of compression).

If you're really interested in exploring this, I'd be interested to see what you can come up with. Maybe we can exchange notes. I've devoted much of my career just being interested in figuring out what ZB is doing, or at least coming up with something of my own that can rival what it's doing. For just about everything else I've tackled over the years from raytracing to particle simulations to fluid dynamics and video processing and so forth, I've been able to at least come up with demos that rival or surpass the performance of the competition, but not ZBrush. ZBrush remains that elusive thorn in my side where I just can't figure out how they manage to be so damned efficient at what they do.

If you really want to crawl before you even begin to walk (I think raytracing is a decent enough start, but if you want to start out even more fundamental) then maybe a natural evolution is to first just focus on image processing: filtering images, painting them with brushes, etc, along with some support for basic vector graphics like a miniature Photoshop/Illustrator. Then work your way up to rasterizing some basic 3D primitives, like maybe just a wireframe of a model being rendered using Wu line rasterization and some basic projection functions. Then work your way towards rasterizing filled triangles without any lighting or texturing, at which point I think you'll get closer to ZBrush focusing on raytracing rather than scanline with a depth buffer. However, doing a little bit of the latter might be a useful exercise anyway. Then work on rendering lit triangles, maybe starting with direct lighting and just a single light source, just computing a luminance based on the angle of the normal relative to the light source. Then work towards textured triangles using baycentric coordinates to figure out what texels to render. Then work towards indirect lighting and multiple light sources. That should be plenty of homework for you to develop a fairly comprehensive idea of the fundamentals of rasterization.

Now once you get to raytracing, I'm actually going to recommend one of the least efficient data structures for the job typically: octrees, not BVH or KD-Tree, mainly because I believe octrees are probably closer to allowing what ZB allows. Your bottlenecks in this context don't have to do with rendering the most beautiful images with complex diffuse materials and indirect lighting and subpixel samples for antialiasing. It has to do with handling a boatload of geometry with simple lighting and simple shaders and one sample per pixel which is changing on the fly, including topologically. Octrees seem a little better suited in that case than KD-tree or BVHs as a starting point.

One of the problems with ignoring the fundamentals these days is that a lot of young developers have lost that connection from, say, triangle to pixel on the screen. So if you don't want to take such rasterization and projection for granted, then your initial goal is to project 3D data into a 2D coordinate space and rasterize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a book that starts at a low level, with framebuffers and such, try *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice*, by Foley, van Dam, et al.  It is an older, traditional text, but newer books tend to have a higher-level view.  For a more modern text, I can also recommend *3D Computer Graphics* by Alan Watt.  There are plenty of other good introductory texts available -- these are just two that I am personally familiar with.

Neither of the above books are tied to OpenGL -- if I recall correctly, they include the specific math and algorithms necessary to understand and implement 3D graphics from the bottom up.

Comment: Also, note that generating the data to draw using algorithms is different from accessing a video card and actually setting that pixel data there. If you want to do the latter as well - you'll need some sort of device driver level knowledge unless you use an API that already does that work for you.